# display custom cursor in myweb page

Tags: image, cursor

i want to do custom cursor in particular place in my webpage. i have number of images when mouseover on images then cursor image change as a custom cursor. how to do ?

Comment: Ever heard of Google? Or the 'Accept Question' button?

http://www.hypergurl.com/customcursor.html

Comment: This does not belong on stackoverflow. Ask here: http://doctype.com/
Hint: make and image follow your mouse cursor - not like that IE only BS.

Comment: @sims, the CSS cursor property (and the ability to use url() as a property) is part of the CSS standard: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/ui.html#cursor-props

Comment: Nice about CSS. I should have actually read the content. Instead, I immediately gagged when I saw: "If your browser is IE6..." and "IE 6 browser users and above..." Perhaps the page author has something wrong with his CSS, but it doesn't work in FF.

Answer (score 2):

What you are probably looking for (based on your very limited description) are CSS Cursors:

- [W3Schools - CSS Cursor](http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/pr_class_cursor.asp)

Answer (score 1):

A quick google search found this: http://www.hypergurl.com/customcursor.html

Comment: It's a safe bet that the OP has looked at search engines and not found information that solved the problem.